# How do I use previous data with .catch in JS?

Tags: javascript

```
await populartimes(markers[i].placeID)
    .then(out => {temp = 'Currently ' + out.now.currently + ' full.'})
    .catch(out => {temp = 'Live data is not currently available. Historically, ' + markers[i].name + ' would be ' + out.now.usually + ' full.'})
    .catch(out => {temp = 'There is currently no data available.'});
```

I am trying to make it so that my first .catch statement uses the first returned data again except this time to check for another variable(now.usually rather than now.currently which is checked for in the .then statement). How do I do this? I have written this but I am pretty sure that the out passed to the first .catch is just the error statement from the .then.

TIA!

Comment: Why you `catch` twice? And you can keep whatever variable you want at the global scope (which is always accessible).

Comment: There are a couple things "fishy" here. Using [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) with `then` (which sometimes is fine but highly irregular) and then using two `catch`. I think it'd be best for you to check out the docs for Promises again. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: To help you with this code, can you describe what you want to happen when the  `populartimes` function fails? It's not clear from your code.

Comment: @MartinZeitler, it is impossible to be sure, but it appears as if @ZKJ is attempting to fallback to the case when `.currently` (which must be a getter or otherwise configured property, not a raw property, or else accessing it won't throw), is unavailable by using `.usually`, and then fallback AGAIN if that is unavailable, to just not use any of the data. This may be unnecessary, but depending on the usecase it may be required to gracefully fallback.

Comment: @yeerk You got it exactly right, that is what I am trying to do. -Martin Zeitler I will use a global variable if there is no better way, thanks! -Dominik I'll give it a read thank you! As for what I want to happen -yeerk described it perfectly - basically the populartimes function returns an object which has 2 properties, in the case that the first property does not return a value then I want to check if the second one returns. If both do not then its set to a default message. Thank you all for the help! I understand how to do it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately promises don't curry data values after an error is thrown. You are already using one temporary variable though, so why not two?:

```
var temp;
var out!: any;
await populartimes(markers[i].placeID)
    .then(value => {
        out = value;
        temp = 'Currently ' + out.now.currently + ' full.';
    })
    .catch(() => {
        temp = 'Live data is not currently available. Historically, ' + markers[i].name + ' would be ' + out.now.usually + ' full.';
    })
    .catch(() => {
        temp = 'There is currently no data available.';
    });
```

However, I would be cautious about mixing promise handling with await statements. If `populartimes` is an async function your code will work as expected, however if it is a normal function that returns a promise, your code won't handle the case when it throws an error (a function that returns a promise can either reject the promise OR throw an error).

Using only `await` and `try/catch` your code would be equivalent to:

```
var temp;
try {
    var out = await populartimes(markers[i].placeID);
    try {
        temp = 'Currently ' + out.now.currently + ' full.';
    } catch {
        temp = 'Live data is not currently available. Historically, ' + markers[i].name + ' would be ' + out.now.usually + ' full.';
    }
} catch {
    temp = 'There is currently no data available.';
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the help, I will check the code for populartimes to see if it is an async function and if it isn't make the necessary adjustments. One quick question, the populartimes call takes a long time to resolve - would that be a result of me using await?

Comment: No, I don't believe so. It depends on your JavaScript engine, but in v8 (what NodeJS uses) `await` is exceptionally fast, very close to the speed of promises, which are already very fast. I recommend looking into `JavaScript profiling`, and then running a profile to determine what is slowing your code down. It is often surprising what code is slow, but I don't think it will be the `await` statement.